# Ignoring whitespaces, carriage return and tab characters between elements when parsing an XML file

Tags: xml, whitespace, sax, character, xerces

I want to parse an XML file with SAX Xerces C++ while ignoring any white spaces, carriage return and tab characters that are NOT within element attributes or within a start and end element. I want to ignore white spaces, carriage returns and tabs that would be between tags.

For instance in following XML file:

```
<tag1 attr1="val 1"><tag2>my text here</tag2>
```

[many white spaces here]          `</tag1>`

I want to preserve white spaces within the strings 'val 1', 'my text here', but ignore the carriage return, and the many whitespace characters between the ending `</tag2>` and the ending `</tag1>`.

I tried to use a boolean flag 'withinElement' set to true in `startElement()` and set to false in `endElement()` methods, but that does not prevent me to ignore whitespace characters between `</tag2>` and `</tag1>` for instance.

Should that be done in the `characters()` method? 
and how to do it as there does not seem to be a way to know where we are precisely when the `characters()` method is invoked?

Comment: I think I have solved my problem using: 
`boost::algorithm::trim_copy()`

Answer (score 0):

You could ask the parser to validate the XML file and then you will get all the ignorable whitespaces through the method `ignorableWhitespace` and the "good" whitespaces through `characters`.